# python multiprocessing pool signal

Tags: python, signals, multiprocessing, pool

I got a small problem I'm beginner with the multiprocessing module in python and I have to create a pool which can be able to be stopped any time by a SIGINT.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, current_process
import signal
import time
import os

class Processor(object):
    def __init__(self, stack):
        self.stack = stack
        self.pool = Pool(processes=4, maxtasksperchild=1, initializer=self._init)

    def _init(self):
        cp = current_process()
        cp.daemon = False

    def launch(self):
        self.result = self.pool.map(func, self.stack)
        self.pool.close()
        self.pool.join()

def func(j):
    a, b = j
    time.sleep(1)
    return a * b

def breaker(*args):
    p.pool.terminate()
    p.pool.join()

def main():
    a = 4, 9
    b = 5, 7
    lst = [a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b]
    global p
    p = Processor(lst)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, breaker)
    p.launch()
    ret = p.result
    for i in ret:
        print i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print os.getpid()
    main()
```

Without any signal the code is executed perfectly but when I send a signal to this process this don't work anymore and the breaker function is never called.
If someone has an idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

breaker function does get called but it doesn't tell your main to exit, if you add:

```
sys.exit(os.EX_OK)
```

or any other exit at the end of breaker then it will actually exit.

also you may want to move this:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, breaker)
```

before Pool definition which should stop un-handled keyboard interrupt in child processes

to get the partial results you may want to do the following...

your launch would have to become:

```
# start the workers
for el in self.stack:
    self.result[el] = self.pool.apply_async(func, (el, ), callback=your_callback)

#wait for results
for work in self.result.items(): # or iteritems if you're on pre python3
    work[1].get()

self.pool.close()
self.pool.join()
```

this will do the results one by one as async calls, and your callback will have the opportunity to save them somewhere for later.

map will not give you that as it returns only once at the end of call, so you can't get to the partial results

then you need your_callback somewhere that will write the results to global list of results:

```
def your_callback(result):
    global_list.append(result)
```

the ordering may be all over the place though...

now your results will be available one by one in global_list, you can output this in your main() or in your breaker()

Comment: Your solution work perfectly but I still have another problem which is not mentioned above. How could I get the results of map because I stop him during his run but he might have done some tasks until I send a SIGINT. And I can't get them. Do you got an idea why ?

Comment: I'm afraid that retrieving partial result is more problematic... map is probably not what you want to use for that, i can post some code that would be able to do that in a minute

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I don't use map anymore and I'm now using apply_async your solution works perfectly thank you very much